# How can I add message key to KafkaSink in Apache Flink 1.14

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

As stated in the title I need to set a custom `message key` in `KafkaSink`. I cannot find any indication on how to achieve this in the `Apache Flink 1.14` docs.
At the moment I'm correctly setting up the `KafkaSink` and the `data payload` is correctly written in the `topic`, but the `key` is `null`.
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should implement a `KafkaRecordSerializationSchema` that sets the key on the `ProducerRecord` returned by its `serialize` method.

You'll create the sink more-or-less like this:

```
KafkaSink<UsageRecord> sink =
    KafkaSink.<UsageRecord>builder()
             .setBootstrapServers(brokers)
             .setKafkaProducerConfig(kafkaProps)
             .setRecordSerializer(new MyRecordSerializationSchema(topic))
             .setDeliverGuarantee(DeliveryGuarantee.EXACTLY_ONCE)
             .setTransactionalIdPrefix("my-record-producer")
             .build();
```

and the serializer will be something like this:

```
public class MyRecordSerializationSchema implements
        KafkaRecordSerializationSchema<T> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String topic;
    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper =
        JsonMapper.builder()
            .build()
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
            .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

    public MyRecordSerializationSchema() {}

    public MyRecordSerializationSchema(String topic) {
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    @Override
    public ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> serialize(
            T element, KafkaSinkContext context, Long timestamp) {

        try {
            return new ProducerRecord<>(
                    topic,
                    null, // choosing not to specify the partition
                    element.ts.toEpochMilli(),
                    element.getKey(),
                    objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(element));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Could not serialize record: " + element, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this example is also setting the timestamp.

FWIW, this example comes from https://github.com/alpinegizmo/flink-mobile-data-usage/blob/main/src/main/java/com/ververica/flink/example/datausage/records/UsageRecordSerializationSchema.java.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow access the key that Flink uses, e.g. after a keyBy operation?

Comment: The current key can be accessed from the Context passed to a KeyedProcessFunction.

Answer (score 1):

This example is for scala programmers. Here, we are defining a key by generating UUID for each events.

```
import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.sink.KafkaRecordSerializationSchema
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord

import java.lang

class MyRecordSerializationSchema extends KafkaRecordSerializationSchema[String] {


  override def serialize(element: String, context: KafkaRecordSerializationSchema.KafkaSinkContext, timestamp: lang.Long): ProducerRecord[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]] = {
    return new ProducerRecord(
      kafkaTopicName,
      java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString.getBytes,
      element.getBytes
    )
  }
}
```

In the main class, will have to pass an instance of this class while defining the kafka sink like this:

```
val sinkKafka: KafkaSink[String] = KafkaSink.builder()
   .setBootstrapServers(bootstrapServerUrl) //Bootstrap server url
   .setRecordSerializer(new MyRecordSerializationSchema())
   .build()
```